# Find execution time of recursive function

Tags: c#, function, recursion, timer, stopwatch

I could use stopwatch to find execution time of a code

Example:

```
timer.Start();
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    ...
}
timer.Stop();
lTime.Text = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

But what if I call a function that use recursive?

```
timer.Start();
recur(a, b);
timer.Stop();
lTime.Text = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

Its show execution time 0.

Edit: This code running fine... I had one error in the recursive function...

Comment: Put your timer to the method calling your recursive function.

Comment: Don't use `Timer` for this - use [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: @Oded I use stopwatch I just called timer

Comment: I see - just to confuse people, eh?

Comment: Be interesting to find out what you are trying to achieve from this. Are you trying to analyse performance and look for areas to improve. If so, then you might be better served by a profiling tool such as [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/features/key-features). It will give representative results that will show you where to look not how long it will take.

Comment: @Oded :D you could see tags

Comment: Sure, and you could name your variables less confusingly ;)

Comment: Could you add code to ensure that your recursive function is recurring, or alternatively stick a wait at the top of the recursive function to ensure it takes time to run i.e. `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`.

Comment: @Oded - Thinking about it, the Timer classes seem to be poorly named.  They don't actually time anything, they just execute on a regular interval.  It seems like the Stopwatch should have been called Timer.  Although I can't readily come up with a more appropriate name for the Timer class.  Of course, it's too late to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StackOverflow.Demos
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            recur(10000, new object());
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine( timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void recur(int a, object b)
        {
            if (a > 0)
                recur(--a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah its really working... My code just have some error..

Comment: No worries - if you want a hand resolving your code issue post it up in a new question :).